# With DNS, what does 0.0.0.0 stand for?

Tags: windows-7, dns

With DNS, what does 0.0.0.0 stand for?

I have it set (Network and sharing settings → change adapter settings → Wireless network connection → Internet protocol v4 → Use the following DNS settings) to 0.0.0.0 but what do those numbers represent?

Comment: I'm 80% sure that means to use the default DNS.

Comment: Default DNS by whom? I'm using a VPN. Would that be the default DNS as set by the VPN provider or by the ISP?

Comment: ISP I believe. Some routers come with a DNS that redirects your page to a page of ads if you enter an incorrect URL but by default I think it's your ISPs default. Maybe 0.0.0.0 *is* the ISP default, I'm not sure. That's why I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: Probably not the ISP's because when I go to dnsleaktest.com my ISP does not show up.

Comment: It depends where this is being used.

I can think of two possibilities. 
As Chipperman573 has said it could mean to use the default DNS that is specified elsewhere.
It could also be a way of the GUI in question expressing that no DNS server has been specified.

Without knowing the context its difficult to say more.

Comment: OS is windows 7. Network and sharing settings --> change adapter settings --> Wireless network connection --> Internet protocol v4 --> Use the following DNS settings --> 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 2):

Because `0.0.0.0` is not a valid destination address, this is simply an invalid configuration.

DNS servers, like other regular IP services, need to be addressed by a valid destination IP address, ie. anything but `0.0.0.0` and `255.255.255.255` minus a few reserved ranges. Depending on the actual network configuration, other addresses might be invalid, too, like `192.168.2.0` and `192.168.2.255` on the `192.168.2.0/24` network.
Additionally, for name resolution to work, the server has to be reachable.

There is one valid use for the `0.0.0.0` address though: When listening for connections, it means “listen on all interfaces on this computer”.

Some programs may erroneously display `0.0.0.0` where a value is not set.

Windows (8.1 in my case) will also prevent you from entering a `0` octet in the first group of an IP address.

Answer (score 1):

The IPv4 address 0.0.0.0 usually represents an unknown address, in instances where an address must be specified.

It makes a good placeholder in cases where an IP address must be specified but none is yet known. It is not supposed to be seen on the wire (or on the air) after DHCP IP autoconfiguration completes. The reason why you see it is likely that you have explicitly said that you will specify the DNS server IP addresses yourself, but have not yet specified the addresses to any DNS servers.